# Replacing string that does not include given pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to replace any character in the string that does not match the given pattern

```
300x300
```

If a string is something like the following:

```
blahblah300x300dingding
```

I would like to remove the following bolded text:

**blahblah**300x300**dingding**

So far i've created this regex expression, but so far it only removes the end characters that don't match, but i'd like it to match the beginning ones that dont match too.

Here is my expression:

```
(?<=(.*300x300)).+
```

I'd like to use `String.replace(REGEX, '')` to remove any value that does not match the pattern.

Comment: It should be `s.replace(/(300x300)|[^]/g, '$1')`. Or `s.replace(/(\d+x\d+)|[^]/g, '$1')`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem properly I think the regex can be much more simple

First approach

```
const paragraph = 'blahblah300x300dingding';
const regex = /300x300/;
const [found] = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found);
// will log => "300x300"
```

Second approach

```
found = paragraph.replace(/(300x300)|[^]/g, '$1') ;
console.log(found);
// will log => "300x300"
```

Or if you want to match any string that is `numberXnumber`

```
 found = paragraph.replace(/(/\d*x\d*/)|[^]/g, '$1') ;
 console.log(found);
 // will log => "300x300"
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I ended up using test.replace(/((\d+)x(\d+))|[^]/g, '$1') ;

Could you please explain what the [^] does and the $1?

Comment: [^] is the negated set, so matches any character not in the set. $1..$n are static properties, the mozilla docs have a good explanation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n. You can try your regex out on a website like regexr.com, which will help you break down expressions while you're learning